# JavaScript alert dynamically created variable name

Tags: javascript

I got the follow code:

```
var image1 = 'aaa.jpg';
var image2 = 'bbb.jpg';
var image3 = 'ccc.jpg';
var image4 = 'ddd.jpg'; // all dynmically created

current = 1; // dynamically changing value, in this case between 1 and 4
```

What I need now is to alert `alert(image1);` but on this way: `alert(image + current);`

Is it even possible this way? I hope I explained clearly what I need.

Comment: Thats a nice solution too Jack, not easy to create with PHP but would work :D

Comment: How do you create the variables using PHP currently? Seems a bit like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Like that: <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<?php
    $x = 1;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ergebnis))
    {
        echo "var image" . $x . " = '" . $row['image'] . "'; ";

        $x++;
    }
?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
this.image1 = "aaa.jpg";

alert(this["image" + "1"]);
```

Comment: That works too so I accept that :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, I think you've on the right path. But here are some things to consider...

1. Put the dynamically created variable in quotes to make them a string:

`var image1 = 'aaa.jpg';`

2. When you out put in the alert box put the word 'image' in quotes also. That way it will be a string too:

`alert(eval('image'+current));`

3. The alert box won't actually show the image. It will only show the name of the image that is stored in the variable.  I think this is what you're going for.

Good Luck!

**I see you edited the question to put it the dynamic variable in quotes. Well done.**

Comment: 1: I did oO 2: It alerts "image1" but not the value of image1 3: wth xD

Answer (score 0):

I solved it the way one user posted it and deleted his answer (why?):

```
alert(eval('image'+current));
```

Answer (score 0):

As it was suggested in the comments and based on your PHP code from the comments: Create a JavaScript array to store your data instead of creating lots of variables. You can accomplish it for example like this:

**Create string containing all images**

```
<?php
    $images = '';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $images .= ( $images ? ',' : '' ) . '"' . $row['image'] . '"';
    }
?>
```

**Output**

```
var images = [<?php print $images; ?>];
alert (images[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're clearly working with a collection, so you should create an array structure in this case:

```
<?php 

$images = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ergebnis)) {
    $images[] = $row['image'];
}

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var images = <?php echo json_encode($images) ?>;
</script>
```

You can then reference each image path via, e.g. `images[0]`.